# (LARAVEL) I am simply trying to link to a photo in my storage/app/images directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do I link to my storage directory or should I store these somewhere else. I am creating a basic cms and would like to be able to show photos on each post. right now I am trying

```
<img src="{{ Storage::get('images/53bb15cceac4f7ecf9fb51cb78296f68.jpeg') }}" 
        class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

What happens right now is it returns absolutely nothing.

Comment: You found the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Images must be stored in a directory that is publicly available to the world. The storage directory should not be publicly available.

You should create a folder somewhere under your `/public` directory and put your images there (for example `/public/images`). Then you can link to them like:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/53bb15cceac4f7ecf9fb51cb78296f68.jpeg') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

Now, you can store images in the storage directory, but you would have to create a Laravel route that has logic to retrieve the data of the image and stream it back as image data, however that would add a lot of complexity just to view an image, and would mean having to load the entire Laravel framework for every image, which is not very efficient.

### Edit

Since you're dealing with user uploaded images, you may want to follow some of the advice provided by the Laravel documentation. By default, the `store($location)` method will place the file in the `storage/app/{$location}` directory.

However, Laravel comes with a preconfigured `public` storage filesystem. If you pass in this filesystem as the second parameter, (`store($location, 'public')`), it will store the file in the `storage/app/public/{$location}` directory. To make this directory publicly available, you can run the `storage:link` artisan command, which will create a `/public/storage` symbolic link to your `/storage/app/public` directory.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

So, if your code is `$request()->file('photo')->store('images', 'public')`, it will store the photo as `/storage/app/public/images/53bb15cceac4f7ecf9fb51cb78296f68.jpeg` and you access via `{{ asset('storage/images/53bb15cceac4f7ecf9fb51cb78296f68.jpeg') }}` (assuming you've run the artisan command to setup the symbolic link).

Documentation on [storing uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#storing-uploaded-files)
Documentation on the [public filesystem disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Ok, Right now I am using this request()->file('photo')->store('images'); to upload to the storage/app/images directory, How do I store in the public images folder?